# Is it possible to automate the process of educating Watson?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

We look forward to maximise the use of Watson in our project. For this purpose we have to educate waston with all project documents, User manuals etc and use the Watson Conversation API possibly. But this seems a manual process of creating entities, intents and then dialogues. Is there a way Watson can identify potential entities and intents on its own? Or some way of automating or fast tracking the process of identifying entities, intents and creation of dialogues.

```
    Can RPA (Robotic process automation) tools such as WinAuto or BluePrism be combined to use for this purpose ? Please suggest.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're seeking to do, Watson Conversation Service may not be the right answer for your use case.

What I read, looks more like a case for Watson Discovery Service, possibly combined with Watson Knowledge Studio.

You can read more about it here: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2016/12/watson-discovery-service-understand-data-scale-less-effort/?spMailingID=27478889&spUserID=MTY4Mzc0OTEyOTIxS0&spJobID=960800840&spReportId=OTYwODAwODQwS0
And secondly on the integration:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/wks/wks_mapublish.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In the API documentation it states that methods are available to create all artefacts (workspaces, entities, intents, dialognodes etc..)

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#update_workspace

But the SDK's don't support it yet (at least the Java SDK)